# How do you allow only admins to read certain fields in a document in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection of documents where there are some fields anyone should be able to only read and some fields where only the admin should be able read/write. My rules look something like

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /MyCollection/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
      match /publicField {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I get a `Missing or insufficient permissions` err when I try to read the documents. How do I allow anyone to read the `publicField` of any `MyCollection` document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the access of individual fields in a single document.  Match patterns can only target document paths, and don't know anything about document fields.  If anyone can read a document, then they can always read the **entire** document.

If you want to change the permissions of some data in a document, they need to be split into another document in a collection that has appropriate security rules.

You might be interested in reading: [The trade-offs between performance, cost, and security with Firestore](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-tradeoffs-between-performance-cost-and-security-with-firestore-ef72ba43f316)

Comment: Nice article. Will leave this unmarked as the answer in case Firebase implements security at the field level in the future.

Comment: That will not happen.  Access will always be at the document level, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Ok, I'll trust you on that